# Package and install a xxx.desktop file with javapackager

Tags: linux, maven, javapackager

I've packaged an application with [Maven's JavaPackager](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager) plugin targetting Linux.

Everything is working fine except that I don't find how to package and install a "xxxx.desktop" file for my application.

Without this file, 1/ the icon on the launcher is ugly, 2/ the application cannot be found with a Search.

Here is my plugin's config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.fvarrui</groupId>
    <artifactId>javapackager</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.zparkingb.zploger.GUI.Zploger</mainClass>
        <generateInstaller>false</generateInstaller>
        <administratorRequired>false</administratorRequired>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- With JRE -->
            <id>bundling-for-platform-complete</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <platform>linux</platform>
                <name>${project.bundle_finalname}${package.buildnamesuffix}</name>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/FULL</outputDirectory>
                <createTarball>true</createTarball>
                <createZipball>false</createZipball>
                <bundleJre>true</bundleJre>
                <customizedJre>false</customizedJre>
                <!--From settings.xml-->
                <jrePath>${package.jrePath}</jrePath>
                <jdkPath>${package.jdkPath}</jdkPath>
                <!--Special for Linux-->
                <linuxConfig>
                    <pngFile>assets/linux/Zploger.png</pngFile>
                    <generateAppImage>true</generateAppImage>
                    <generateDeb>false</generateDeb>
                    <generateRpm>false</generateRpm>
                    <wrapJar>true</wrapJar>
                    <categories>
                        <category>Utility</category>
                    </categories>
                </linuxConfig>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So I'd need to end up with file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/com-zparkingb-zploger-GUI-Zploger.desktop
```

with a similar content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Zploger for Scores
Icon=/home/vboxuser/Desktop/ZplogerScores/Zploger.png
```

Or even having the icon placed somewhere in `~/.local/share/icons/xxx/xxx` and having the ".desktop" file refering to it as `Icon=Zploger`

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is probably far from being ideal, but I am limited in that I am building a Linux solution from a Windows environment.

The solution is based on the following principle:

1. Have the application startup script checking for the presence of the icons and the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/`.
2. If it doesn't exist, copy these from the package.

So the solution must

1. Adapt the default startup script in order to do that extra check
2. Add in the packaging the desktop file and the icons.

In the end, the solution is comprised of the following 4 steps:

1. Add to the project folder the icons and the desktop file. I've put these in a `bundledata/linux/assets` folder. The folder name is free but cannot be `assets\` because this one is reserved for JavaPackager and cannot one of the Maven resources folder because I want these files to packaged separately.
2. Provide an adapted [`startup.sh.vtl`](https://gist.github.com/lgvr123/4bb751e9a48c89e30a75176121cb9342#file-startup-sh-vtl-L62-L89) velocity template which goal is to add to the startup script instructions to copy the icons and a valid desktop file.

The icons are copied to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/`.
And I provide "./16x16", "./24x24", ... "./1024x1024". And also "./scalable" with a SVG version of the application icon.

The desktop file is named `my-main-class.desktop` (in my case `com-zparkingb-zploger-GUI-Zploger.desktop`) and is copied into `~/.local/share/applications/`

3. Have that script modifying the `xxx.desktop` to push the current script path.
4. Adapt the pom.xml.
   In the io.github.fvarrui.javapackager plugin's config, add the following instruction:

```
<additionalResources>
    <additionalResource>bundledata/linux/assets</additionalResource>
</additionalResources>
```